# Ball hitting the helmet behind the keeper

Tags: rules, cricket

If the ball is missed by the keeper, glances off the non-worn helmet behind him and travels to the boundary, how many runs are awarded for that?

Answer (score 6):

This is 5 penalty runs and any runs completed prior to the ball striking the helmet and any penalty for wide or no ball.  See [law 28.3](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws/the-fielder).